# Cast in java unsigned types

Tags: java, android, c++

I read that in java there is not unsigned data types. I need send this message:

```
A5A5   0008     F005     0001     00000003
uin16  uint16   uint16   uint16    uint32
```

I did this:

```
int prefijo =  0xA5A5;

int numbytes = 0x0008;

int tipo =  0xF005;

int id = 0x0001;

long estado =  0x00000003;
```

is the correct way? and now i need push this information in a byte [] to send to my device. How can i do???

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[12];
```

thanks

Comment: signed-ness is only a matter of interpretation. `0xff` is read `-127` in java, but `255` in C if it is considered unsigned. The real problem you are facing is rather that you are using `int` (32 bits) for 16 bites shorts. Use `short`

Comment: @njzk2 I think you mean -1 in Java if you're using a byte :)

Comment: so, in cases that i have uint16 i have to use short and in cases that i have uint32 i have to use int no?

Comment: yes, whatever that is. (i never really can wrap my head around those 2-complement things.) The point stands, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `short` uses 16 bits
- `int` uses 32 bits
- `long` uses 64 bits

In any case, as you are using hexadecimal values, the sign can be ignored:

```
byte b=(byte)0x81; //1000 0001
```

It works no matter the sign that it gets in decimal "interpretation".

Said so, you should use short for the first 4 numbers and int for the last one.